# body onload function repeating

Tags: javascript

Not sure if this is a little vague but I'm grappling with how the client-side interacts with the server-side at the moment. I started with an exercise to understand on-click events better and have realised I don't understand when or how pages refresh.

I have some 'span' tags. The span tags have an 'onclick' in them which toggles between a couple of images using innerHTML in the function that's called. I also have a button with an onclick that will display an image.

All images are initially set with an onload function in the body tag.

What's obviously happening is that whenever I click a span or the button it's contacting the server which causes it to run the onload event. I see an image for a split second then everything goes back to what the onload function says. I tried taking the onload out of the body tag and running loadFunction() with a separate button. Basically the same result. When I click it the images appear for a split second and disappear. I tried a global variable which starts at zero and is changed to 1 at the end of loadFunction() which allows an if statement at the start of loadFunction(). Same problem - the variable simply gets reset to zero every time because it's redeclaring and setting the global variable at the top of my javascript file.

There's obviously something fundamental to the whole server-side client-side system that I haven't learnt. If anyone thinks they know what that is please let me know.

The three lines that call functions:

```
<body onload="loadFunction();">
<span id = "showImage1" onClick="formSubmit1()">&nbsp;</span>
<button class="link" onclick="checkSquares();">Highlight</button>
```

Comment: This is all client-side stuff from what you are saying. Could you please put it in a jsFiddle, so we can look at the behavior?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code in these functions. I suspect that `formSubmit1()` is causing a form submission, and that is reloading your page.

Comment: Awesome. I had my button inside form tags. I've removed them at it's fixed it. Thanks so much Mike.

Comment: @acl77 great - if it was my answer that helped you, would you mind marking it as an accepted answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button tags will submit the form back to the server.  span, will not, but 'formSubmit' does (I'm unclear on what you want to happen here, maybe you want to show a different image when the page reloads?).

If you don't want the button to submit to the server, then use <input type=button> instead.